# How do we know that LCM works the same as Phi for the RSA cryptosystem?

Tags: cryptography

In the case of Euler's phi function, we know from the Euler generalization of Fermat's little theorem that $M^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1$ mod n. However a lot of modern RSA implementations use LCM ($\lambda(p-1,q-1)$), where $pq = n$, instead of $\phi(n)$. How do we know that any $d$ that is coprime with LCM(p-1,q-1) will produce $m^{ed} \equiv m$ mod n?

Comment: What's $\lambda$?  Do you understand that $\phi(pq)=(p-1)(q-1)$ if $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes?

Comment: $\lamba$ is just least common multiple here. I understand the $\phi$ bit, but I dont understand why it also applies to LCM. I understand that it might have something to do with the fact that $\lambda(p-1,q-1)$ divides $(p-1)(q-1)$, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: If $M^\lambda \equiv 1\pmod p$ and $\pmod q$, then $M^\lambda \equiv 1 \pmod {pq }$ by the Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: If $M^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$, then $M^\lambda\equiv 1\pmod p$

Comment: See also the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

Comment: Might help you; [More than one private key for RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87583/18298)